# Change Size of Game in XNA

Tags: xna

I don't know a better way to say this, but I'm not looking to change the size of the window. I'm creating a maze, whose size that can be changed via scripting. As such, that may make the maze bigger what the window shows (even on full screen. Is there a way to shrink/enlarge the actual game inside the window?

Comment: I think the better solution might be to display a window that will scroll as the player moves about the screen. If you shrink/stretch the game world your presentation will be anything but consistent across mazes.

Comment: My concern is that it's a maze, and that players would get lost if it scrolls.

Comment: I'd call that a feature of any maze, promoting the user getting lost that is. But another option is to limit the maze within a reasonable maximized size and have it as the min size of the window. I think there's going to limits to shrinking/stretching no matter what if you plan to have a nice UX.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you're asking is generally just a bad user experience, cause the size of the game will change, if the maze changes size.

That being said, what you're asking is technically possible. The way to do it would be to use a matrix for SpriteBatch.Begin's last parameter.

This matrix would look something like

```
Matrix.CreateScale(windowWidth / gameContentTotalWidth, windowHeight / gameContentTotalHeight, 1);
```

This will scale your game content to always be drawn within the screen. However this means if you make a large maze, you're likely to end up being unable to navigate it, cause you'd be having troubles seeing where you're going.